# How to debug Spring Boot @ConfigurationProperties?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have 2 "properties" class : AppProperties and QuartzProperties, bound to application.properties and quartz.properties. They are both in the same package, they have both the same annotations :

```
@Component
@PropertySource("classpath:xxx.properties")
@ConfigurationProperties
```

Properties are using the "camelCase" convention both in .properties file and .java files.

But AppProperties is working (properties are injected) and QuartzProperties is not working. I'm not receiving any error or warning. What should I do from now to get feedback on what is not working ?

Comment: So your class is not Configuration annotated it is component. From spring documentation `Add this to a class definition or a @Bean method in a **@Configuration class** `.

Comment: You may have missed one is working while the other is not. So how could the working one work without being part of a @Configuration class ?

Comment: @mallikarjun please, read this for be aware what u can use `@ConfigurationProperties` with `@Component` too, not only with `@Configuration`. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-typesafe-configuration-properties

Comment: Thanks for info.

Answer (score 3):

So what I did to debug this is fall back to using "@Value" on each attribute/properties instead of using the Spring boot specific "@ConfigurationProperties".

It worked, and then going back to @ConfigurationProperties also worked. Sorry no rationnal explanation here.

UPDATE : I have to say what may have tricked me is when u debug, u can see getters of *Properties classes called once (by some technical class in Spring I guess) before the corresponding setters, so the first call gives a default value, not the value from .properties files.